# Partially block light fixture

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, ceiling, ceiling-fan, light

I recently installed a ceiling fan and light fixture which works well except that the light produces an unfortunate glare in one part of the room. I'd like to block the light from shining in that one direction. Is there a good way to do this?

The light comes from two bulbs that are within a frosty half globe under the fan. Searching for solutions has not turned up anything. My best thought so far is to put some foil or similar material inside the globe. There isn't much extra space inside but there is room for something thin like that.

Comment: What type of light bulbs?  Need to be careful of what you use, if the bulbs produce heat   Frosted globe should eliminate glare spots except straight down.

Comment: The bulbs are size A19 LEDs. Could foil cause issues with heat?

Comment: LEDs have more possible ideas, they won't burn stuff.  Foil(guessing aluminum) should work, but might point glare in another direction, plus darken the direction the glare is now.  Do not block the opening of the frosted globe, need it for air circulation/heat escape, LEDs do not like heat.